# How to design a custom grid using bootstrap 3 grid system?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have a grid design like the image below with the use of bootstrap 3 framework ?

**Note:** Blocks are images ...

[image]

i have tried here is the [example](http://bit.ly/1mR7yh1)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"> <a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 1</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 2</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 3</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 4</a></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"> <a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 5</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 6</a></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 8</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 9</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 10</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 11</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail" href="">Box 12</a></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What exactly is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have edited my question to show you what i've tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/600"></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/600x300"></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="//placehold.it/300"></a></div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS to override padding/margins etc..

```
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}

.row.no-gutter .thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter .thumbnail>img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/108971

Comment: great solution but does that respect booststrap convention?

Comment: i have posted a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630604/how-to-design-a-custom-grid-using-bootstrap-3-grid-system-best-practices

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can achieve it by following this instructions:

1. Go to the [bootstrap customize build](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page.
2. Go to **Layout and grid system** section.
3. Modify the **@grid-columns** from the ***default value 12*** to the value that will work with your design, I think ***15 will be great***.
4. Also modify **@grid-gutter-width** from the ***default value 30px*** to be something like ***15px***, so can view good with your design "*this value used to define the space between the columns*".
5. Download your custom build to start your project which will be like this image:

[image]

hope this will help you.