# How to design a custom grid using bootstrap 3 grid system best practices?

Tags: grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382599/how-to-design-a-custom-grid-using-bootstrap-3-grid-system)

is it possible to using boostrap 3 to build a grid like so:

desktop > mobile

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the same method as outlined in the linked post. The only difference I might add is I like to use nested `<div class="row">` and change the CSS slightly:

```
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:5;
  padding-left:5;
}

.row.no-gutter .thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter >img.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
}


.row.no-gutter-mob [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}

.row.no-gutter-mob .thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter-mob >img.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
}
```

To handle the different mobile layout use the `visible-*` class attribute [documented here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to make one layout visible on mobile and one visible on larger screen resolutions. **Note: you are creating two separate layouts and hiding one depending on screen widths.** Below is the code I came up with.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Desktop Layout -->
    <div class="row no-gutter visible-lg visible-md">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail"></a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter visible-lg visible-md">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div> 
        <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
    </div> 
    <!-- Tablet/Mobile Layout -->
    <div class="row no-gutter-mob visible-sm visible-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter-mob visible-sm visible-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter-mob visible-sm visible-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter-mob visible-sm visible-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter-mob visible-sm visible-xs">
        <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you be more specific or provide the code you are working with? Because I have used this method multiple times before.

Comment: there is a bigger gap between the first 400x400 gap and the one below http://bootply.com/111903

Comment: and if you play with the size of the window the squares aren't squares

Comment: that's a shame cause it looked exactly like the pictures :)

Comment: Yes I understand you will need to play with it to meet your needs. You may need to make a third version for medium screens. I was answering the question of how to do separate layouts on different screen sizes which this is the best solution I have found.